# Programmable sound bricks

Tags: customization

[Regarding this component](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55206c04#T=S&O=%7B%7D)

It comes in several versions, each producing a different sound when pushing the button, e.g. a barking dog or doorbell. However, the sound is "fixed", is there any way to replace the sound with one of your own choosing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be programmed, but it requires specialized equipment

Here is one connected to a circuitboard 
[image]

The external board is wired straight to the internal board. It plays the "doorbell then dog bark" sound from the brick in set 5771 - Hillside House.

Searching the number on the chip (39VF020) reveals it's a simple flash memory chip.

The board (AMA9AA) brings up pages from a Chinese company, Alpha Microelectronics, thatseems to specialize in voice/sound synthesizing hardware. There are references to software called EZSpeech and FlashWriter. There are download links for the software on their website, but they are password protected.

([by mpfirnhaber on Eurobricks](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/138680-prototype-lego-sound-brick/))

This not LEGO related hobby store can make them with custom sounds 
[TopdragonHK](http://www.topdragonhk.com/eshowshop.asp?id=47)